# Insert null datetime from sql table into datagridview silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagridview

I have problem with null values, I want to insert from sql table nulls ( from datetime column) into datagridview, and datagridview return error.

> Communication Exception was unhandled by user code

Code:

```
public class Pismo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PW { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Data_Wysylki { get; set; }
}   

public ObservableCollection<Pismo> ReadPisma(int id_pismo)
{
    ObservableCollection<Pismo> result = new ObservableCollection<Pismo>();
    string nwConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(nwConn);
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Pismo wiersz = new Pismo();
            wi.Id = dr.GetInt32(0);
            wi.PW = dr.GetString(1);
            wi.Data_Wysylki = dr.GetDateTime(2);
            result.Add(wi);
        }
        dr.Close();
        return result;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        Pismo wi = new Pismo();
        wi.Id = e.Message;
        result.Add(wi);
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();

    };
}
```

```html
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Wysyłki" Binding="{Binding Data_Wysylki, StringFormat='yyyy/MM/dd'}"/>
```

I try to add this below

```
if (wi.Data_Wysylki.HasValue) wi.Data_Wysylki = dr.GetDateTime(16);
```

after that error didnt show but in datagridview all  column (even with some dates) was null

Comment: Are all your dates null valued? Why would you want to insert those anyway?

Comment: I have in my sql table column name: date of shipment. And 
some cells are completed and others are waiting to complete in the future.